# Telling a friend I normally hangout with on a holiday, I don't want to this time

Tags: friends, politeness, saying-no, friend-groups, invitations

A national holiday is coming up :) I have a friend (call him Joe) I normally hangout with on this holiday. I also see him on a regular basis. This time I would like to hangout with a different group of friends. Joe has been messaging me asking if we're still meeting at the usual spot for the festivities. He said that most people in the group we go with haven't been responding to him but respond to his messages on a different topic.

I feel a bit bad for Joe. I don't think it would be a good fit if I invite him to what I plan on doing. How can I nicely tell Joe I won't be meeting with him this time?

Comment: What do you feel is wrong with a simple “sorry Joe, I already made other plans”? If you want to soften the blow, offer to spend the night before or day after with him.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because. As written this looks more like a request for help phrasing a statement than navigating an interpersonal situation. Why can't you just tell your friend that you won't be meeting him this time?